# Did the animals that sustained injury in Sing survive?

Tags: sing

In Universal's movie Sing, a few animals were injured: a snail, who was crushed by a buffalo, and supposedly taken to a hospital, albeit not on camera; and a camel, who was seen in an ambulance. Is their health confirmed, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snail, [Ray](http://sing.wikia.com/wiki/Ray), is fully recovered at the end of movie and watching Meena sing with his friend Richard, who accidentally stomped on him.

Likewise, the camel, [Pete](http://sing.wikia.com/wiki/Pete), is also fully recovered and attends the grand reopening of the theater at the end of the film.